# compare memory usage between variables outside es6 class and bind to this

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wonder which way is better in real run-time about **memory footprint** and **release time**.

#### outside class

```
const foo = {
  ...
};

class Base {
  // use foo below as const variables
}
```

#### bind to this as property

```
class Base {
  constructor() {
    this.bar = {
      ...
    }
  }

  // use this.bar as property below
}
```

which way above will occupy more memory?
if I follow the first one that define const variables outside class, what time which be released from memory?

thanks for your time :)

Comment: Note that in the first case, while *foo* is a `const` its properties aren't.

Comment: As an alternative to the first (which is probably better btw), you could define it as `Base.foo` if the variable makes logical sense to be with the class.

Comment: @4castle thanks for your suggestion, I'll consider it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case a single `foo` object will be hold in memory until the realm is shut down.

In the second case it will be an instance of `this.bar` per `Base`.

Keeping in mind the Garbage Collector:

1. Is not standardised and not even required for an implementation
2. Is not deterministic (can run at any point in time, or never)

Based on that we can speculatively state that:

First case is "better"* if at least one instance of `Base` is created.

And now addressing your very questions:

> if I follow the first one that define const variables outside class, what time which be released from memory?

An object would become garbage collectible when it's not reachable. So, when all references to it are lost. Then, the memory is "released" after the GC is triggered.

But practically, you must follow the performance optimisation rule of thumb: measure.

If something *is* a problem for you, first take debugger/profiler and prove scientifically it actually is what you think it is.

---

*It all really depends

Comment: thanks for your smart reply. I hold only one instance as singleton which be created from class `Base`, so I want to find the better way to store object.